# How can I reduce the memory cache size of the game?

Tags: clash-royale

I realize that the game producing enormous cache data on my phone.

Is it possible to stop it?

*P.S. I don't know that is it related to my phones specifications or not. My phone is LG Nexus 5 and have Android 6.0.1 on it.*

Comment: well what is your phones hardware ? which version you have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the way that it is, there is no way to change it. There are lots of other posts about this online, see the following links for clarification:

https://www.quora.com/Why-does-mobile-game-such-as-Clash-Royale-or-COC-store-so-many-cache

https://forum.supercell.com/showthread.php/1379750-Clash-royale-app-cache

Comment: but if he is using a phone with old/unsuported hardware, it will increase the cache

Comment: It says in the post exactly what he is using. He says he says: My phone is LG Nexus 5 and have Android 6.0.1 on it.